# Stop a website from automatically redirecting me due to a JS injection

Tags: xss, exploit

I'll keep it short and clean and illustrate it. 
There is a chat that has a JS/AJAX exploit that some hacker is using to redirect the site, Im trying to access the site without being redirected.
The site : https://chatws.com (Login as a guest to see what I mean)
The injected code is something like this :

```
if(my_username != "userexample" && user_rank != 9) {
    var dis = 'message string';
    $.ajax({
        url: "system/chat_process.php",
        data: {
            high: 'yellow" ></span>  <img src="" onerror="if(my_username == `userhere`) {} else { logOut(); } "/',
        },
    });
}
```

Which the hacker injects in the AJAX.POST method (a message to all chatters)

All I want to do now is to access the site before being INSTANTLY redirected.

I tried these methods :

```
Window.stop();
```

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return window.location = "#";
}
```

Anything else I could try?

Comment: Are you getting logged out once the attacker sends something to the chat, or is the injection happening on your side of things?

Comment: Seems like you should be able to set my_username and user_rank?  Are those read from cookies?

Comment: `$=Boolean` should break it a bunch

Comment: Solved! I sent an AJAX POST and I had to be fast enough to clear his message to be able to stop the injection